# Получить все не забронированные авто

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, join

Есть таблицы Car и Booking (для бронирования авто), структуру второй привёл ниже.

```
class Booking(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Booking"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    car_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("Car.id"), nullable=False)
    during: Mapped[Range[datetime]] = mapped_column(TSRANGE, nullable=False)
```

Стоит задача написать запрос, который бы мне возвращал все авто из таблицы Car, которые свободны в определённый временной отрезок [datetime1:datetime2].

Пробовал так:

```
query = (select(CarModel).join(BookingModel)
         .filter(not_(BookingModel.during.overlaps(Range(date_start, date_end)))))
result = await self.db.execute(query)
r = result.scalars().all()
```

но это работает только когда в Booking есть как минимум одна запись для конкретной машины, + если записей (броней) несколько, то в ответ идут несколько копий записи одной машины. А мне требуется возвращать не более одного экземпляра машины, и в случае, когда для какой то машины в принципе нет записи в Booking, запрос отдавал эту машину (так как она считается свободной).